# Dying hair even though it is not white

Tags: hair

I want to die my hair. I'm a man and I do not have white/gray hair, it is still black. I know if i dye it, it needs to be a natural color. So is it permissible for me to dye my hair?

Answer (score 0):

In the name of Allah, the most gracious, the most merciful.

I will begin with some hadiths, then elaborate as short as possible to get the main points across.

*Jabir b. ‘Abdullah reported that:*

> Abu Quhafa (the father of Abu Bakr) was brought in front of the Prophet on the day of the Conquest of Mecca. His head and beard were white like hyssop. Whereupon Allah’s Messenger (peace be upon him) said: “Change it with something but avoid black“.

*[Sahih Muslim • Book 37, Hadith 124 • Graded Authentic (Sahih)]*

Basically, if you want to dye your hair, don't dye it black.

---

However...

*Narrated Abdullah ibn Umar:*

> The Prophet (peace be upon him) said: “He who imitates a people is one of them.”

*[Sunan Abi Dawud 4301 • Book 34, Hadith 12 • Graded Reliable Authentic (Hasan-Sahih)]*

This hadith basically says that the prophet is telling us that "No, do not follow what other people of other faiths do" instead we should seek Allah and not worry about what the other people are doing.

---

**So, you may ask: What colors are halal?**

It is narrated:

> The Prophet (peace be upon him) said: “The best things with which grey hair are changed are henna and katam“.

*[Sunan Abu Dawud 4205 • Book 35, Hadith 47 • Graded Authentic (Sahih)]*

Well in this case, the Prophet wants us to dye the colors of: henna (a red plant dye) and katam (type of grass).

---

The Prophet tells men that they should dye our hair as a differentiating factor among the other faiths.

*Allah’s Messenger (peace be upon him) said:*

> “The Jews and the Christians do not dye (their grey hair), so do the opposite of what they do (i.e. dye your grey hair and beards).

*[Sahih al-Bukhari • Book 60, Hadith 129 • Graded Authentic (Sahih)]*